# wagtail: no pages to moderate in the dashboard

Tags: wagtail

I'm new to wagtail. I followed "Get started" in the documentation. After changing home/models.py the documentation is: "You can now edit the homepage within the Wagtail admin area (go to Explorer, Homepage, then Edit) to see the new body field. Enter some text into the body field, and publish the page." There is no button to publish the page. I can save the page, and i can have a preview.

I found in the documentation that new pages should be moderated As an admin I should see them in the dashboard pages.

But there is not such a list.

Answer (score 3):

The 'Publish' and 'Submit for moderation' options appear in the expanding menu alongside 'Save draft':

[image: Wagtail page save options]